# Annoyances with appindicator icon positions (Ubuntu 14.04.2)

Tags: unity, icons, indicator

I have a niggling problems with appindicator icons. The first problem is with the positioning of one particular icon, I've managed to change the order of all but one of my user indicators using the 'ordering-override.keyfile', but one icon refuses to budge, and I was hoping someone would maybe have a solution. The icon that refuses to move is the icon for 'update_indicator'.

Here is my keyfile content:

```
[Ordering Index Overrides]
nm-applet=1
gnome-power-manager=2
ibus=3
gst-keyboard-xkb=4
gsd-keyboard-xkb=5
quiterss=6
qbittorrent=7
Update_Indicator=8
places=9
```

and the output of the dbus-send etc command:

```
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/netspeed/Menu" 
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/Update_Indicator/Menu"
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/classicmenu_indicator/Menu"
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/places/Menu"
object path "/org/kde/statusnotifieritem/1/menu"
object path "/org/kde/statusnotifieritem/1/menu"
object path "/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/nm_applet/Menu"
```

Everything looks fine to me, but no matter how I enter the info for that one icon, it never moves. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

In case you're still looking for an answer: You have to replace underscores with hyphens. So it should read:

`Update-Indicator=8`